# Org mode paragraph promotion

Tags: org-mode

I've got a superior heading and text under it, which is nicely indented. Then I added a sub-heading and put in text, which is also nicely indented even more to the right. Now, I want to get back to entering text indented at the superior heading's level with appropriate indenting:

```
* heading1
 Some text...

 ** heading2
    Some text

 continuation of heading1 text
```

I can't seem to get org-mode to let me go back to the superior heading's indentation column; it wants everything to remain at the sub-heading's indentation column.

Comment: I don't think you can do this. I hope I'm wrong, but as far as I know, org-mode doesn't have a way to end a subsection. A subsection that starts with a second level heading (ie., `** heading2`) only ends at the next heading at the same or higher level (`** heading3` or `* heading 3`). Without introducing a new heading, there's no way to tell org mode that the subsection is finished.

Comment: [Related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30997099/in-org-mode-how-to-break-current-section-and-escape-to-upper-level). @Tyler is correct; there's no way to continue a higher level heading. Use lists to group subitems and make it clear when those end and you continue with the previous content.